# Confusion related to the time complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was going through some of the articles of the leetcode. Here is one of them https://leetcode.com/articles/optimal-division/.

Given a list of positive integers, the adjacent integers will perform the float division. For example, [2,3,4] -> 2 / 3 / 4.

However, you can add any number of parenthesis at any position to change the priority of operations. You should find out how to add parenthesis to get the maximum result, and return the corresponding expression in string format. Your expression should NOT contain redundant parenthesis.

```
Example:
Input: [1000,100,10,2]
Output: "1000/(100/10/2)"
Explanation:
1000/(100/10/2) = 1000/((100/10)/2) = 200
However, the bold parenthesis in "1000/((100/10)/2)" are redundant, 
since they don't influence the operation priority. So you should return "1000/(100/10/2)". 

Other cases:
1000/(100/10)/2 = 50
1000/(100/(10/2)) = 50
1000/100/10/2 = 0.5
1000/100/(10/2) = 2
```

I think the time complexity of the solution is O(N^2) isn't it?

Here is the memoization solution

```
public class Solution {
    class T {
        float max_val, min_val;
        String min_str, max_str;
    }
    public String optimalDivision(int[] nums) {
        T[][] memo = new T[nums.length][nums.length];
        T t = optimal(nums, 0, nums.length - 1, "", memo);
        return t.max_str;
    }
    public T optimal(int[] nums, int start, int end, String res, T[][] memo) {
        if (memo[start][end] != null)
            return memo[start][end];
        T t = new T();
        if (start == end) {
            t.max_val = nums[start];
            t.min_val = nums[start];
            t.min_str = "" + nums[start];
            t.max_str = "" + nums[start];
            memo[start][end] = t;
            return t;
        }
        t.min_val = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        t.max_val = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        t.min_str = t.max_str = "";
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            T left = optimal(nums, start, i, "", memo);
            T right = optimal(nums, i + 1, end, "", memo);
            if (t.min_val > left.min_val / right.max_val) {
                t.min_val = left.min_val / right.max_val;
                t.min_str = left.min_str + "/" + (i + 1 != end ? "(" : "") + right.max_str + (i + 1 != end ? ")" : "");
            }
            if (t.max_val < left.max_val / right.min_val) {
                t.max_val = left.max_val / right.min_val;
                t.max_str = left.max_str + "/" + (i + 1 != end ? "(" : "") + right.min_str + (i + 1 != end ? ")" : "");
            }
        }
        memo[start][end] = t;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make your quesiton rely on off-site resources. Explain the problem you're trying to solve, and post the (relevant part of the) code here. And explain in more detail why you think the complexity is N^2.

Comment: @m69 updated the question accordingly

Comment: Since all entries are positive integer, isn't the answer always putting the parentheses to group together the second entry to the last entry? Because the first entry will always be in the numerator, and the second entry will always be in denominator, and by putting the rest in the numerator, we will get the maximum result. And this can be achieved by putting parentheses to group together the second element to the last element.

Comment: Oh, just realized that my comment is one of the proposed answer in the link, and your question is about the time complexity of *your* algorithm